# Webdriver: How to handle alert boxes globally

Tags: selenium, webdriver, alert

Scenario: In my automation suite I want to handle alert boxes globally as it may appear anywhere in the website due to business requirement. I do not want to use try catch everywhere so what I want is to write the code in one function and use it in a way so that It can handle the alerts globally wherever it occurs.

Comment: Do the alert boxes appear in a predictable manner ie. related to the workflow? Or are these random occurrences similar to survey questions popping up anytime and anywhere?

Comment: Hi, no it can't be predicted in advance. These are generated based on some uncertain conditions, depending upon the user actions and network access.

Answer (score 1):

One option (the one we use where I work) is to call a method to clear alerts any time one might appear:

```
public void clearAlert() {
    Alert alert = ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent().apply(this);
    if (alert != null) {
        alert.accept();
    }
}
```

That method is in a class that implements the WebDriver interface, so 'this' is a WebDriver instance, effectively.

For any actions that create an alert, our framework calls `clearAlert()` after performing the action (assuming the alert is expected and should be ignored).

If your alert boxes are truly unpredictable, you could call `clearAlert()` before or after performing every action, which shouldn't be too difficult if you have a well-designed framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
public void verifyAndAcceptAlert(WebDriver driver){

  try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //to do something
    }

  }
```